# Is there a way to upload image with other input to a json-server database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json-server

I have a json-server API database(db.json) and want to be able to store images along with other input values. Is there a way to achieve it.

I have tried using FormData but to no avail

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type    : 'POST',
            url     : `http://localhost:3000/cars`,
            data    : new FormData($('#myForm')[0]),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            dataType : 'json',
            encode   : true
        })
        .done(function(data){

            console.log(data)

        });

    })
})
```

I want to be able to have the image stored as json object and be able to retrieve with when I call the API with GET method for image to be displayed

Comment: Images are not supposed to end up in a database table or json file. Store the image in a folder as some *UUID.extension*, and in the database save only that *name* for future reference.

Comment: Not without writing a custom endpoint. json-server isn't configured for this out of the box. Then as Roko points out it doesn't make sense storing in json file either